# How to create a sparse DataFrame from a list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I create [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) from a list of dicts like this:

```py
pd.DataFrame([{"id":"a","v0":3,"v2":"foo"},
              {"id":"b","v1":1,"v4":"ouch"}]).set_index(
                 "id",verify_integrity=True)
     v0   v2   v1    v4
id                    
a   3.0  foo  NaN   NaN
b   NaN  NaN  1.0  ouch
```

Alas, for some inputs I run out of RAM in the `DataFrame` constructor, and I wonder if there is a way to make pandas produce a [sparse](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html) `DataFrame` **from the list of dicts**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use the `dtype='Sparse'` for this.

If all elements are numbers you can use `dtype='Sparse'`, `dtype='Sparse[int]'` or `dtype='Sparse[float]'`

```
data = [{"id":'a',"v0":3,"v2":6},
        {"id":'b',"v1":1,"v4":7}]
index = [item.pop('id') for item in data]
pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, dtype="Sparse")
```

If any value is a string you have to use `dtype='Sparse[str]'`.

```
data = [{"id":'a',"v0":3,"v2":'foo'},
        {"id":'b',"v1":1,"v4":'ouch'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype="Sparse[str]").set_index("id",verify_integrity=True)
```

Comment: Alas, not all my data is numeric (please see edit)